# "Where did I see this" or "Where did I saw this"?

Tags: grammar

My friend and I have been arguing about it. I may be wrong, but is the former of the given choices the correct one?

Comment: *Where did I **see***..... is correct.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul - Unless you're talking about cutting wood.

Comment: @HotLicks, Good point! :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did I see... is correct.

whenever you use did (past), the base form comes in (present simple).